# Fine tune a caffe model with my data, the result is unexpected

Tags: caffe

I want to fine tune a caffe model that the model has been fine tuned based on googlenet, my data is 23 classes, so the 'num_output' of 'loss1/classifier''loss2/classifier''loss3/classifier' should be set to 23.

However, when I experimented use both 23 and googlenet's default parameters 1000, they both can run and the result of iteration 3000 use 23 is 0.80 and the result of iteration 15500use 1000 is0.86, it is unreasonable.

why get those results?

[image]

Comment: Why do you think that it is unreasonable? I am unable to understand your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Comment: welcome to SO. please do not post screenshots of code/logs etc., rather copy-paste the actual text (with proper formatting) so that search engines will be able to better index your post.

Comment: if you have 23 classes (assuming with roughly the same number of examples per class) than random classifier will have accuracy of ~1/23 which is 0.043 (4.3%). You are getting accuracy of 0.80 (80%) and improving to 0.86 (86%). **why do you think this is not reasonable?** what were you expecting?

Comment: First of all, don't do unnecessary experiments such as replacing 23 by GoogLeNet's default 1000. That 1000 means 1000 classes, as you know. So if you have 23 classes, stick to it in all three fields: `loss1/classifier, loss2/classifier, loss3/classifier`. Also, I think if you have `num_output: 1000` for a 23 class data, and you are getting 86% accuracy, it is unreasonable. However, your experiment was unreasonable to start with, so I recommend that you don't think about it much. Just focus on doing experiments correctly.